# add smtp in php mail function

Tags: php, email, smtp

I need help to add a smtp into my forgot password function. The function does not send out email, I checked with the host and they said that i must add their smtp into the script.
The smtp is : smtp.axentus.net

I dont know where i should add it and how.

Please help.

```
   <?php
$_language->read_module('lostpassword');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    if($email!=''){
        $ergebnis = safe_query("SELECT * FROM ".PREFIX."user WHERE email = '".$email."'");
        $anz = mysql_num_rows($ergebnis);

        if($anz) {

            $newpwd=RandPass(6);
            $newmd5pwd=md5($newpwd);

            $ds = mysql_fetch_array($ergebnis);
            safe_query("UPDATE ".PREFIX."user SET password='".$newmd5pwd."' WHERE userID='".$ds['userID']."'");

            $ToEmail = $ds['email'];
            $ToName = $ds['username'];
            $vars = Array('%pagetitle%', '%username%', '%new_password%', '%homepage_url%');
            $repl = Array($hp_title, $ds['username'], $newpwd, $hp_url);
            $header = str_replace($vars, $repl, $_language->module['email_subject']);
            $Message = str_replace($vars, $repl, $_language->module['email_text']);

            if(mail($ToEmail,$header, $Message, "From:".$admin_email."\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"))
            echo str_replace($vars, $repl, '<div id="box-login">
        <div id="box-login-content">
          <form method="post" action="lostpassword/">
            <b>Your account '.$ds['email'].' has been found.</b><br /><br />
            You will get an e-mail with your account data in a few seconds.
         </form>
        </div>
      </div>');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise using PHPMailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer  /   http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) - it's very easy to use, I use it myself for a site that needs smtp

To send using SMTP with PHPMailer just add the lines:

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.axentus.net";
```

Comment: where can i add those lines?

Comment: Sorry mate I was on holiday.. See this link for an example of how to use PHPMailer http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebsmtp

Comment: In the download, there should also be a folder named 'example' in which you will find a file named 'test_smtp_basic.php'.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at http://4rapiddev.com/php/phpmailer-send-email-html-content-with-utf-8-encoding/ which provides fully php source code for you be able to configure sending email through SMTP.

Comment: So change to phpmailer is the onmly way to get this workning?
I am new with php so i dont know how to do.

Comment: It's not the only way, just the easiest. Super simple to use, and works great - hence it's popularity.